# How to make a paper-card scrollable

Tags: polymer

I'm using polymer's paper-card (I can't use paper-dialog because of [this](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-dialog/issues/152) issue). How can I make it scrollable?

For example, in this code I would like to be able to scroll the card when it gets too large for the screen. Right now it just makes some of the content unreachable.

```
<paper-card>
    <h2>[[someMessage]]</h2>
    <div id="someReallyLongStuff"></div>
    <paper-button raised on-click="doSomethingAndCloseCard">OK got it:)</paper-button>
</paper-card>
```

I've tried limiting the paper-card's size with max-height but that doesn't help.

---

EDIT

Here are photos of another example to clarify my problem:
In the first photo I have a small paper-card that fits the screen, but when it gets bigger it doesn't become scrollable, but goes out of page boundaries to make some of the content unreachable

[window with small paper-card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phHAV.png)

[window with longer paper-card that is too big for the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uXDS.png)

I'm looking for something like [paper-dialog-scrollable](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-dialog-scrollable) only for paper-card

Answer (score 0):

**!!!Update with code example at the bottom!!!**
**Paper-dialog**
However, I used to work around that backdrop problem, related to the paper-dialog, with this answer that I found somewhere. I used this in a Polymer 1 project so I am not certain if it will still work in version 2. You definitely have to adapt the function.

```
<paper-dialog with-Backdrop on-iron-overlay-opened="patchOverlay"></paper-dialog>

// Fix with-backdrop for paper-doalog (Polymer1)
// https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-dialog/issues/7

patchOverlay: function (e) {
   if (e.target.withBackdrop) {
      e.target.parentNode.insertBefore(e.target.backdropElement, e.target);
   }
}
```

**Paper-Card**
If you are still looking to work with the paper-card Element and find yourself unable to change the width read further.

I have never tested that code but a presume that you will have to use the Polymer mixin for the paper-card.
 I don't think max-length is valid CSS better would be to use max-width or max-height.

```
paper-card {
  --paper-card: {
    max-width: 500px;
  };
}
```

**Update**
I have added a code example using the basic paper-card provided by Polymer [here](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-card/demo/demo/index.html)
Long story short, I gave the text container a fixed height and added overflow auto to it. This way scroll bars will be added as soon as the text doesn't fit in it's container. This can be improved by adding the overflow only to the y-axes with "overflow-y: auto;"

```js
// Load webcomponents.js polyfill if browser doesn't support native Web Components.
var webComponentsSupported = (
  'registerElement' in document
  && 'import' in document.createElement('link')
  && 'content' in document.createElement('template')
);

if (webComponentsSupported) {
 // For native Imports, manually fire WebComponentsReady so user code
  // can use the same code path for native and polyfill'd imports.
  if (!window.HTMLImports) {
    document.dispatchEvent(
      new CustomEvent('WebComponentsReady', {bubbles: true})
    );
  }
} else {
 // Load webcomponents.js polyfill
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.async = true;
  script.src = 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/StartPolymer/cdn/1.8.1/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js';
  document.head.appendChild(script);
}
```

```css
    paper-card {
      --paper-card: {
        width: 100px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      };
    }
    
    .card-content {
      width: 200px;
      height: 100px;
      overflow: auto;
    }
```

```html
<!-- <base href="https://gitcdn.xyz/cdn/StartPolymer/cdn/v1.11.0/components/"> -->
<!-- <base href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/StartPolymer/cdn/v1.11.0/components/"> -->
<base href="https://rawcdn.githack.com/StartPolymer/cdn/v1.11.0/components/">

<link rel="import" href="iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout.html">
<link rel="import" href="paper-card/paper-card.html">


<style is="custom-style">

</style>


<paper-card heading="Emmental" image="http://placehold.it/200x100/FFC107/000000" alt="Emmental">
  <div class="card-content">
    Emmentaler or Emmental is a yellow, medium-hard cheese that originated in the area around Emmental, Switzerland. It is one of the cheeses of Switzerland, and is sometimes known as Swiss cheese.
  </div>
  <div class="card-actions">
    <paper-button>Share</paper-button>
    <paper-button>Explore!</paper-button>
  </div>
</paper-card>

<script>

window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {

});

</script>
```

Comment: I saw this paper-dialog backdrop solution as well but it didn't work in my case. As for the paper-card styling - the content is long and not wide so max-width doesn't do anything and max-length either... they don't make the paper-card to become scrollable

Comment: I've added photos to clarify my problem

Comment: I updated my answer and have added a code example so you can run it and take a look.

Comment: Maybe you can accept my answer if this solved your problem

Comment: I did but it's not visible because I don't have enough reputation... :(